# Add Geometry Attributes doesn't work for feature classes but does work for shapefiles

Tags: geometry, fields-attributes, arcgis-10.5, feature-class

I'm trying to add start and end point coordinates to a line feature using the LINE_START_MID_END geometry property of the Add Geometry Attributes tool. Every time I use the tool on a feature class in a geodatabase I get an error message:

```
<Error>

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File &quot;c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.5\ArcToolbox\Scripts\AddGeometryAttributes.py&quot;, line 292, in &lt;module&gt;
    AddGeometryAttributes(fc, geomProperties, lUnit, aUnit, cs)
  File &quot;c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.5\ArcToolbox\Scripts\AddGeometryAttributes.py&quot;, line 49, in AddGeometryAttributes
    fields = CreateOutputFields(fc, geomProperties, hasZ, hasM)
  File &quot;c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.5\ArcToolbox\Scripts\AddGeometryAttributes.py&quot;, line 244, in CreateOutputFields
    arcpy.da.ExtendTable(fc, &quot;OID@&quot;, narray, &quot;_ID&quot;)
RuntimeError: General function failure [FeatureClassInQuestion]
</Error>

<Error>Failed to execute (AddGeometryAttributes).</Error>

</Errors>
```

when I convert the feature class to a shapefile and run the Add Geometry Attributes tool on it, it runs fine and produces the points.

I've tried disabling M and Z values in environments without success. I suppose I could just convert the feature class to a shapefile and convert it back to solve this issue but I'm curious to see if anybody else has run into this and found a simpler way to fix it?

Comment: Do you have an unusual name for your OBJECTID field? It should be OBJECTID for a geodatabase FeatureClass.

Comment: Do you have permissions to edit the feature class? Are there any locks on the data? Since the tool manipulates the input, it's possible it cannot complete because of permissions/locks.  When you create a new shapefile, it's doubtful there are any locks preventing the process from running.  Also, ensure you're using a feature layer as the input.  A quick way to do this is to add the feature class into ArcMap, and then use the drop-down menu for Input Features and select the feature class from the list.

Comment: Yes, the OBJECTID field is named OBJECTID.   I've tried using the drop down to make sure that its a feature class. I've also made a copy of the original and immediately run it again to ensure that there were no locks to no avail. The tool works on all the other geometry properties UNTIL I use LINE_START_MID_END.

Comment: **Update: The tool worked after I reimported the feature  from scratch, and ran the tool on Centroid then LINE_START_MID_END. I think there might have been some kind of issue with the leftover START_X field and/or having had a lock on it that took several minutes to break from.

Answer (score 1):

Today I got exactly those same three errors (line 292, 49 and 244) when using *[Add Geometry Attributes](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/add-geometry-attributes.htm)*. But when I exited the editing mode it worked as it should, and when I again entered editing mode the errors came back. Also, the tool *[GPX to Features](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/conversion-toolbox/gpx-to-features.htm)* was sensitive in the same way. So, try exiting editing mode before using the tool.